# Why is this template example code not compiling?

Tags: c++, templates, lnk2019

I am trying to make an example of using templates in order to learn how to use them. I have made a project in Visual Studio 2010 C++ with three files:

Controller.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Example<int,string> example;

    example.appols(5, "Hi");

    return 0;
}
```

Foo.h:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

template <class T, class E>
class Foo{
public:
    void printThis(T t, E e);
};

template <class T, class E>
class Example{
public:
    void appols(T t, E e);
};
```

Foo.ipp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T, class E>
void Foo<T, E>::printThis(T t, E e){
    cout << "FOO! " << t << ' ' << e << endl;
}

template<class T, class E>
void Example<T, E>::appols(T t, E e){
    cout << "APPOLS!! " << t << ' ' << e << endl;
    Foo<T,E> f;
    f.printThis(t,e);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Template Practive, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Controller.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Example<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::appols(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?appols@?$Example@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAEXHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Matthew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Template Practive\Debug\Template Practive.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Could you help me see what I have done wrong here and where `error LNK2019` is coming from?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to include `Foo.ipp` in `Foo.h`, after the class definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Deciphering the Error Message**

Let's try to decode the error message first:

> ```
> 1>Controller.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
> "public: void __thiscall Example<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::appols(int,class
> std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"
> (?appols@?$Example@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAEXHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) 
> referenced in function _main
> ```

We can start to reduce to noise/signal ratio in this error message.

The part with `(?appols@?$Example@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@...` is just C++ *name mangling*. It's intended for the C++ compiler, and it's not something meant to be human-readable. So we can just discard it.

The simplified error message becomes:

> ```
> 1>Controller.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
> "public: void __thiscall Example<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::appols(int,class
> std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"
> referenced in function _main
> ```

The first line tells us that there is an *"unresolved external symbol"*. Let's try to identify it, looking at the next lines.

The parts:

> ```
> class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>...
> ```

are just the long name of `std::string` (which corresponds to `std::basic_string` template with `char` as the character type and using the default `char` traits and the default allocator).

So, we can further reduce the noise, substituting `std::string` instead of those verbose parts:

> ```
> 1>Controller.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
> "public: void __thiscall Example<int,string>::appols(int,string)"
> referenced in function _main
> ```

Now the error is much clearer.

The `__thiscall` part is just a calling convention used by default on C++ member functions.

So, the linker is complaining about this method:

> ```
> "public: void Example<int,string>::appols(int,string)"
> ```

which corresponds to your `Example<T,E>::appols()`:

> ```
> template <class T, class E>
> class Example{
> public:
>     void appols(T t, E e);
> };
> ```

when `T=int` and `E=std::string`.

This corresponds to what you have in your `main()` function in Controller.cpp:

> ```
> Example<int,string> example;
>
> example.appols(5, "Hi");
> ```

---

**Diagnosis and Solution to the Problem**

The problem is that all the template source code must be in *header files*, not in .cpp files.

In fact, the compiler needs the definition of the template code in order to instantiate it.

So, you can move the code from your Foo.ipp file to Foo.h (or just `#include "Foo.ipp"` from your Foo.h), and add `inline` to the template function definitions:

```
// New code in Foo.h

template<class T, class E>
inline void Foo<T, E>::printThis(T t, E e){
    cout << "FOO! " << t << ' ' << e << endl;
}

template<class T, class E>
inline void Example<T, E>::appols(T t, E e){
    cout << "APPOLS!! " << t << ' ' << e << endl;
    Foo<T,E> f;
    f.printThis(t,e);
}
```

Note also that `using namespace std;` is really bad in header files, since this will pollute the global namespace for all the clients that include your headers. Just use the `std::` prefix explicitly in header files (e.g.: `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.).